# Add voice commands to Android app

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-voice

I want to integrate voice actions from 'ok Google' assistant to my app.
Like WhatsApp did in the attached images.

Any references in how to do it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**[Android Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#android_link) is currently in developer preview. You can build actions that use this feature, but they can't be published at this time.**

You can ask the user to continue an interaction via your Android app. This helper allows you to prompt the user as part of the conversation. You'll first need to associate your Android app with your Actions Console project via the [Brand Verification](https://developers.google.com/actions/console/brand-verification) page.

You will need to create a [deep link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) to your Android app and then create a Dialogflow intent that specifies the corresponding event for the helper intent (actions_intent_LINK).

To have the assistant connect directly to your app, you'll need to setup implicit invocation.

> Implicit invocation: When users invoke your Action without using its
>   name (e.g. "Hey Google, I need a chicken soup recipe"). The Assistant
>   matches the user's request based on various signals, and presents the
>   user with a selection of Actions they can choose to fulfill their
>   intent.

To add your intent for deep linking and implicit invocation, do the following:

1. In the Dialogflow Console left navigation, click on Integrations.
2. In the Google Assistant card, click Integration Settings.
3. List item Under Discovery > Implicit Invocations, click on Add intent and type the name of your intent

[image]

Full details are in step #3 of the [Build Actions for the Google Assistant (Level 2) Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/#3).